# Digital Persona U.are.U 4500 ANSI_381_2004 for Java/Windows

Tags: java, windows, sdk, raster, fingerprint

In a legacy Android project, the corporative fingerprints has been taken using Digital Persona U.are.U 4500 fingerprint reader using `Fid.Format.ANSI_381_2004` format and the library:

```
com.digitalpersona.uareu.Engine
com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fid
com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd
com.digitalpersona.uareu.Reader
```

The fingerprints are stored in a database.
Now I need read these fingerprints in Java/Windows and use it with the same fingerprint reader U.are.U 4500.

The Java/Windows OneTouch library is not compatible with `com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fid.Format.ANSI_381_200`.

Where I can get a Java/Windows library to read an validate these fingerprints?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

does the one touch sdk supports the `ISO_19794_4_2005`?, if so you can convert from ANSI to ISO (`Fmd.ISO_19794_4_2005` to `Fmd.Format.ISO_19794_2_2005`) using one of this methods of the `com.digitalpersona.uareu.Importer` class (use ImporterImpl)

```
public interface Importer {
    Fid ImportRaw(byte[] var1, int var2, int var3, int var4, int var5, int var6, Format var7, int var8, boolean var9) throws UareUException;

    Fid ImportDPFid(byte[] var1, Format var2, int var3, boolean var4) throws UareUException;

    Fid ImportFid(byte[] var1, Format var2) throws UareUException;

    Fmd ImportFmd(byte[] var1, com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd.Format var2, com.digitalpersona.uareu.Fmd.Format var3) throws UareUException;
}
```